# Jenkins 2.0 build cancellation with milestones

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We want to use milestones to cancel older builds. We use multi-branch pipeline in order to build each pull request from Github. The build completes in 4-5 min and it is separated in 5 stages. We want to cancel the current build(no matter in which stage is it) when the new change is pushed to Github(a new build started).

So we assign one milestone at the beginning of the build. We use build number for milestone so when a new build is started it completes the next milestone so the previous build got canceled.

The problem is that the pipeline is terminated immediately and sometimes this leave it in an incorrect state.

Can we configure the build to wait till the current step finishes before canceling it?

Another option will be to have different milestones after each stage. In this case, we would like not to cancel build if another build completes the current milestone but just not to enter the next milestone. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
/* This method should be added to your Jenkinsfile and called at the very beginning of the build*/
@NonCPS
def cancelPreviousBuilds() {
    def jobName = env.JOB_NAME
    def buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER.toInteger()
    /* Get job name */
    def currentJob = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)

    /* Iterating over the builds for specific job */
    for (def build : currentJob.builds) {
        /* If there is a build that is currently running and it's not current build */
        if (build.isBuilding() && build.number.toInteger() != buildsNumber) {
            /* Than stopping it */
            build.doStop()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "incorrect state", could this be solved?

Maybe you could achieve this with a milestone/lock combination. 
We use a lock around our deployment step, this way it could not be interrupted.